# Could not create aws sqs queue for multiple environment?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-codestar

The yml file in aws sqs has
Resources:
  MyQueue: 
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName:"mytestqueue"

how to handle the MYQueue when creating a stage environment,
it is throwing Queue already exists!

how to add MyQueue to stage in template.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to ignore naming the resources manually, you can't perform updates on such resources. Let the service create the name which can help you with updates.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-sqs-queue-name

"If you specify a name, you can't perform updates that require replacement of this resource. You can perform updates that require no or some interruption. If you must replace the resource, specify a new name."

Comment: do we need leave the queue name empty i.e(QueueName:""), does that make a  new queue every time run a code pipeline? then how could we find the queue name  to trigger in lambda function?  @omuthu

Comment: no,whenever there is a need to update SQS, it will safely replace a new queue and it will use EventSourceArn of SQS in EventSourceMapping template and will get updated accordingly. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html